# How to combine 2 xml elements in one string with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two elements in my XML file and I want to combine 2 values in one string. This is my XSLT solution:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="housenumber/@value | housenumberletter/@value">
 <houseinformation>
 <xsl:variable name="info" select="xs:string((housenumber| housenumberletter)/@value)" />
 <valueString value="info"/>
 </houseinformation>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

This is my result when I test it in Oxygen:

```
<houseinformation>
<valueString value="info"/>
</houseinformation>
<houseinformation>
<valueString value="info"/>
</houseinformation>
```

Expected result that I want is like this:

```
<houseinformation>
<valueString value="4A"/>
</houseinformation>
```

I also tried the **concat** function but it didn't work.

How can I combine two elements from XML in one string?

UPDATE:

My xml file:

```
<xml>   
    <data>  
    <housenumber value="15"/>
    <houseletter value="A"/> 
    </data>
</xml>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] incl. an input. -- Note that `<xsl:for-each select="housenumber/@value | housenumberletter/@value">` puts you in the context of a `value` attribute; from this context, the instruction `select="xs:string((housenumber| housenumberletter)/@value)"` will never select anything.

Comment: Added my XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your XML example, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="data">
            <xsl:variable name="info" select="(housenumber | houseletter)/@value" />
            <houseinformation>
                <valueString value="{$info}"/>
            </houseinformation>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <houseinformation>
      <valueString value="15 A"/>
   </houseinformation>
</root>
```

If you don't want the space separator, try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="data">
            <xsl:variable name="info" select="(housenumber | houseletter)/@value" />
            <houseinformation>
                <valueString>
                      <xsl:attribute name="value" select="$info" separator=""/>
                </valueString>
            </houseinformation>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="data">
            <houseinformation>
                <valueString value="{concat(housenumber/@value, houseletter/@value)}"/>
            </houseinformation>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$info` variable should be referred to with the `$`. Otherwise, it thinks you are attempting to XPath to an element named `info`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="housenumber/@value | housenumberletter/@value">
  <houseinformation>
    <xsl:variable name="info" select="xs:string((housenumber| housenumberletter)/@value)" />
    <valueString value="$info"/>
   </houseinformation>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Or avoid the variable and just put that expression inline inside of an [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates):

```
<xsl:for-each select="housenumber/@value | housenumberletter/@value">
  <houseinformation>
    <valueString value="{xs:string((housenumber| housenumberletter)/@value)}"/>
  </houseinformation>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I have tried your second solution:

 `<valueString value="{"xs:string((housenumber| housenumberletter)/@value)}"/>`

And I had a error with it then I changed to:

 `<valueString value="{xs:string((housenumber| housenumberletter)/@value)}"/>`

And I get the no result. This is what I get from Oxygen: **The child axis starting at an attribute node will never select anything**

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. I have corrected the code in the answer